# Users in my group can't import boxsdk in python ( SyntaxError: invalid syntax )

Tags: linux, python-2.7, box

When I import the necessary libraries in the python box sdk into my projects it works perfectly, but when ever another user in my group tries to use the same library it gives me the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>
> "/home/-------/.../---------.py", line 2, in
>
> ```
> from boxsdk import Client, OAuth2
> ```
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boxsdk/**init**.py", line 5,
>
> in
>
> ```
> from .auth import JWTAuth, OAuth2
> ```
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boxsdk/auth/**init**.py", line 8,
>   in
>
> ```
> from .jwt_auth import JWTAuth   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boxsdk/auth/jwt_auth.py", line  11,
> ```
>
> in
>
> ```
> import jwt   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jwt/__init__.py", line 17, in
> ```
>
> ```
> from .jwk import (   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jwt/jwk.py", line 60
> def is_sign_key(self) -> bool:
>
>                       ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

This error occurs whether the user uses sudo or not as well as if they import the libraries with this:

from boxsdk import Client, OAuth2

or

import boxsdk

***************** UPDATE

We are all using Python 2.7.12

Answer (score 1):

`is_sign_key()` uses [type annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/).

Compare the output of `python --version` for you and your colleagues. Downrev python interpreters won't recognize type annotations.

Comment: Just checked.. we all have Python 2.7.12